# Chemical or simply a physical reaction? coca cola + liquid propane

Tags: home-experiment, gas-laws

In this video what is that creates the propulsion of the bottle? Is it a chemical reaction or simply a state change?
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VxvJcPToXb0

I think is the propane that passes from liquid to gas, nothing more.

Comment: Apparently the latter.